# Power of function x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

Does anybody know how to find the power of a value in x86 assembly,

Is it possible to shift by the number of times in a value?

For example:

```
  mov x, 30 

  shl eax, x
```

For my example I would like to find 2^32,2^31,2^30.....2^0.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680303/power-of-in-x86-assembly , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412780/power-of-2-with-shr-and-shl-assembly

Comment: To find powers of two, just use bitwise shifts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [power of in x86 assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680303/power-of-in-x86-assembly)

Comment: is a bitwise shift, shr and shl? thanks

Comment: hi, i have read them before i asked this question, i cannot simply 
shl ax,13 as i need to update the value i'm shifting by so it would have to be like shl ax,value but i am not allowed to do this in x86 assembly

Comment: Do you mean something like `shl ax, cl`? You can use `CL` to hold a shift amount and use it to shift.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please incorporate some of the things you've said in response to clarification-seeking comments into your question.

Comment: Also always make sure to read instruction description when not sure about its details. For example `shl r/m,#imm8/cl` will mask the shift-count to only 5 bits, so it's doing `shl eax, (cl mod 32)` (as shifting by 32 on 32b register doesn't make much sense anyway).

Comment: yes Margaret bloom, this is exactly what im looking for! thank you very much. Apologizes for the poor wording of my question, I am a newbie to x86.

Comment: is it possible to move a dword into CL? I would like to keep a counter dword, the maximum value it will have is 32.

Comment: @Alex Just move the least significant byte into `cl` or overwrite all of `ecx`.

Answer (score -3):

with a shx instruction you can only use 1 because rapresent the moviment of bit.

for shl you put out last bit on the left and insert a bit on the right.
for this you multiplay a byte per 2.

while shr you put out last bit on the right and insert a bit on the left.
for this you divide a byte per 2.

so if you want storage a powr you must move a calculate data into other register.
example 32bit assembler: 2^32

$    mov eax,2

mov ecx,number of power

xor ebx,ebx

loop_power: shl eax,1

add ebx,eax

loop loop_power $
you ha power of 2 in ebx

Comment: That is not true. x86 has an instruction to shift by a variable amount of bits. One such instruction is e.g. `shl r/m32,cl`.